# Can't create TableLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to create a dynamic table, in which I want to use to left column as a menu which I will hide. To do this I want to create a TableLayout, but I can't. If I do this:

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout () { };
```

I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'TableLayout' could not be found.
```

In the same class I am calling other stacklayouts and even custom views which draw a graph, but I can't create a TableLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TableLayout is an Android class, and does not exist in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. What am I supposed to use if I want to hide a column from a table?

Comment: For a menu, you would typically use a MasterDetailPage.  Or you could create a Custom Renderer for TableLayout, but that would only work for iOS and would require a different implementation for other platforms.

Comment: should have said Android, not iOS in the last comment